# SP13: Custom List Library Line Item Appearing on Another Page

Tags: 2013, javascript, designer-workflow, custom-list, css

Scenario: I have created a custom list with a text column.  The text column has a paragraph of text.  There are 10 individual line items with content in the text column too.

What am I trying to do?  I would like for the four line items to appear on a another page with the text from the text columns in four separate sections.  Example, line item #1 appears on the other page in certain section of the page.  Line item#2 appears on the other page in certain section of the page...etc. All an automatic process.

To resolve:  A few ways I wanted to approach.  Create four web parts on the destination page link back to custom list. But not sure how to have one item appear in designated section.  Another thought would be to create a designer workflow that pull the text into the web part on the destination page.  Not sure if this work neither.  There should be a way be adding css to the individual web parts not 100% sure.

Is there a way this can be done? Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than putting all text in one column - in your scenario it is best to create a different item for each line then you can use Content Query Web Part (CQWP) or list views to show items based on their IDs.

**Edit**
Rather than using IDs - You can add other column to the list for example a "Target Page" column which can be a single line of text for simplicity. For each of your list item you can assign a page to the item and configure the views based on the "Target Page" field value. This way any newly added items would be added automatically to the page based on the view conditions. When users add a new item they also specify the page name or tag in the "Target Page" field.

Comment: I will edit my original question.  that is exactly what I want to do.  I will not put all the text in one column.  each line item will have it's own text that will be placed in text column.  How would I do what you have recommended?  Thanks

Comment: I tried the list views id.  brilliant.  But new items will be added at times.  I cannot change the ID. So I will have to keep creating views.  That will be a lot of work for users.  I was thinking if you can change the id the new content can appear on the other page.   You said "create a different item for each line then you can use CQWP".  Can you elaborate?